# Handle arrays in C# generating xml?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I got a generated class in C# (from a xsd with xsd/c), that got this declaration (together with string-fields, numeric fields and so):

```
private string[] itemsField;
private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;
```

The ItemsChoiceType looks like this:

```
public enum ItemsChoiceType1 {
    colorOfCar,
    colorOfMC,
    colorOfBike,
}
```

So, If we look at the itemsElementNameField, its an array of enums, but how should I fill it, to make every value as an element in my XML-file?

(The method I use to create the xml is:

```
 - XmlSerializer XmlSerRoot = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RootInformation)) (the root of my xml!) 
 - StringWriterWithEncoding strWriter = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
 - XmlDocument documentInXML = new XmlDocument();
 - XmlSerRoot.Serialize(strWriter, rootInformation);  
 - string XmlString;
 - XmlString = strWriter.ToString(); 
 - documentInXML.LoadXml(XmlString);
 - documentInXML.Save(myPath);
```

maybe not of interest, but better to apply some information about it, I thought)    
  
I want this array to be like an ordinary xml-tag in the file, like: `<colorOfCar>Blue</colorOfCar>`

I got all information I need, like if it's a colorOfCar, and the color of it (like blue). But how should the array look like? I mean, how should I fill it to be ok. It's not working with just something like `ItemsChoiceType[1] = "colorOfCar"` (I got this info at this stage). But I cannot figure out how the array should be filled to be ok in the end.

Maybe kind of incomplete information, but I think you undertand what I mean....
The main thing is: how to fill an array to be represented as xml-elements in the end.

Regards,
/E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no choise but follow a xsd, I only got it in my hand from 3.rd part. That's why it looks a bit confusing. But the solution was easier then I thought. I don't know how this work, but id does. I just filled in the arrays with enums, and it looks nice. The other array keep the values.

Kind of strange that it's ok, but it works.

/E